# How to rename xml serialization on web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, serialization

I have a web service written in C# and on this project I added a model called ProjectDTO. I have a web service that returns some objects of this class and I would like that my web service return a node called Project in my xml result and not ProjectDTO, how can I do this?

I tried to add some attributes on my ProjectDTO class like XmlRoot, XmlElement but it does not work.

Thanks

### Edits

```
public class ProjectDTO {
  //some properties
}
```

my web service (.asmx file.. it's a simple webservice from asp.net 2.0) method:

```
[WebMethod]
public ProjectDTO[] GetProjects();
```

My output xml:

```
<ArrayOfProjectDTO ...> 
 <ProjectDTO>
  <Id>...</Id>
  <Nome>...</Nome>
 </ProjectDTO>
</ArrayOfProjectDTO>
```

I would like to rename all places where is 'ProjectDTO' to 'Project' on this xml output, is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: what *exactly* shows in the schema currently?

Comment: Look my edits, thanks :)

Comment: That is tricky when returning an array, since you don't have access to `T[]`, and it is **this** that would need decoration. Personally, I would say: always return a single **wrapper** instance - then you can decorate that wrapper type any which way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knew I had programmed something similar before, it just took me a while to remember.

Here is the format you're looking for:

```
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    [return: XmlRoot(ElementName = "Projects")]
    public ProjectDTO[] HelloWorld()
    {
        return new ProjectDTO[] { new ProjectDTO(), new ProjectDTO(), new ProjectDTO(), }; 
    }       
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "Project")]
public class ProjectDTO
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

The key is the XmlRootAttribute and the XmlTypeAttribute.

Comment: `[return: MessageParameter(Name = "d")]` for JSON.